# TemplateDoesNotExist at /testapp/athlete/create

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have a template on this path `ais/demo/testapp/athlete/acruds/create.html`     And I think its correct but error is

> TemplateDoesNotExist at /testapp/athlete/create
>   testapp/athlete/acruds/create.html, acruds/create.html

why path is comma separated in error ?  and 
still  I am getting this issue

[image]

My `form.py` is

```
class AthleteForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Athlete
        fields = '__all__'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AthleteForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper(self)
        self.helper.form_tag = False

        self.helper.layout = Layout(


                Tab(
                    _('Basic information'),
                    Field('name', wrapper_class="col-md-6"),
                    Field('image', wrapper_class="col-md-6"),
                )
        )

        self.helper.layout.append(
            FormActions(
                Submit('submit', _('Submit'), css_class='btn btn-primary'),
                HTML("""{% load i18n %}<a class="btn btn-danger"
                        href="{{ url_delete }}">{% trans 'Delete' %}</a>"""),
            )
        )
```

My view.py file is

```
class AthleteCRUD(CRUDView):
    model = Athlete
    template_name_base = 'acruds'  # customer cruds => ccruds
    namespace = None
    check_login = True
    check_perms = True
    views_available = ['create']
    fields = ['name', 'image']
        # related_fields = ['invoice']
    custom_forms = {
        'add_': AthleteForm,
            # 'update_customer': CustomerForm,
            # 'add_addresses': AddressesForm,
            # 'update_addresses': AddressesForm,
    }
    modelforms = custom_forms
```

and absolute path of template path is as follow

```
/home/user/Desktop/ais/django-cruds-adminlte/demo/demo/templates/testapp/athlete/acrud/create.html
```

Comment: @Alasdair  what thing you need for this ?

Comment: @Alasdair  I have posted code aswell

Comment: The error says "Django tried loading these templates in the following order...". Because that's an image instead of text, it's hard to compare it to the absolute path.